# 'failed to mount cache', 'failed to mount system', 'flash write failure' in yureka+

Tags: adb, data-recovery, fastboot

i have yueka plus yu5510 , 
i've installed cm13 on it. 
when i'm wiping its cache using twrp 3.0.8 , it shuts down.
after reboot i tried again then it shows 'failed to mount cache' , 'failed to mount system' , failed to mount data'.
size of internal storage,cache,system become 0 mb.
 What have to do ???? pls. help me . i'm stuck  .
i tried every thing under my knowledge like erasing and formatting using fastboot .
i tried to flash stock rom cm12.1 but it says "flash write failure".
also cant change twrp to cwm cause of 'flash write failure'.
pls. pls. can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the eMMC chip got corrupted during the wiping process due to power loss - Always perform dangerous operation while phone battery is unless 50% or above.

If the chip is not damaged, you still can flash your phone with a stock firmware.

You can find flash files  (firmware) and the flashtool [here](http://firmwarefile.com/yu-yureka-plus-yu5510a). Download it and extract its contents.

This [tutorial](https://androidmtk.com/flash-cpb-firmware-using-ygdp-tool) teaches you how to use the flashtool.

Comment: what to do if eMMC chip got corrupted.

Comment: can  i have chance to get alive my device.

Comment: There are tools for repairing eMMC, all are paid though.